# string iterator incompatible for reading eachline

Tags: c++, string, boost, assert, boost-tokenizer

I have an std::ostringstream.
I would like to iterate for each line of this std::ostringstream.

**I use boost::tokenizer :**

```
std::ostringstream HtmlStream;
.............
typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > line_tokenizer;
line_tokenizer tok(HtmlStream.str(), boost::char_separator<char>("\n\r"));

for (line_tokenizer::const_iterator i = tok.begin(), end = tok.end(); i != end; ++i)
{
    std::string str = *i;
}
```

On the line

```
for (line_tokenizer::const_iterator i = tok.begin(), end = tok.end(); i != end;
```

I have an assert error with  "string iterator incompatible".
I have read about this error, on google and on StackOverflow too, but i have diffuclty to find my error.

Anyone could help me please ?

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Nixeus

Comment: Since you don't seem to mind a copy, how about copying the `str()` into an `istringstream` and using `std::getline()`?

Comment: I'm new in the boost:: "world" so i need to learn it !Could you please  give me a sample code for this example ? With iStringStream? Thx :)

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni: I think Chad means to create an instance `std::istringstream` initialized with your string and then use `std::getline()` with it just as you would a file stream. This would avoid using Boost altogether. It could work for you, but it can't do all that `boost::tokenizer` can do (such as ignoring consecutive delimiter characters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to make it non-copying for efficiency/error reporting:

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc6916ae84d7375a)**

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    auto const& s = "hello\r\nworld";

    std::vector<boost::iterator_range<char const*>> lines;
    boost::split(lines, s, boost::is_any_of("\r\n"), boost::token_compress_on);

    for (auto const& range : lines)
    {
        std::cout << "at " << (range.begin() - s) << ": '" << range  << "'\n";
    };
}
```

Prints:

```
at 0: 'hello'
at 7: 'world'
```

This is more efficient than most of the alternatives shown. Of course, if you need more parsing capabilities, consider Boost Spirit:

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c05ed4ffe6eb898)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string const s = "hello\r\nworld";

    std::vector<std::string> lines;

    {
        using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
        auto f(std::begin(s)), 
             l(std::end(s));
        bool ok = parse(f, l, *(char_-eol) % eol, lines);
    }

    for (auto const& range : lines)
    {
        std::cout << "'" << range  << "'\n";
    };
}
```

Comment: `warning: variable \`ok' is unused`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you'll figure out what you need to use it for :) Or not. Note the introduction to the second sample reads: "if you need more parsing capabilities". This implies you need input validation, 99% of the time.

Comment: Could at least have made it `const` ;)

Comment: I didn't want to make it feel _used_ or even _restricted_ in any way. Let the variable blossom, however small it's lifetime. My religion keeps me from crushing the smallest life.

Comment: `const` promotes _freedom_ of life. Freedom to spread the _truth_ of life rather than the pain of death that comes with unexpected mutation! (read: cancer)

Comment: Thanks ! Your first example is uable with my ostringstream  ?

Comment: It sure is. In your sample code you only use the backing storage of the std::stringbuf (`.str()`) anyways. So, that's why I showed steps _from there_.

Comment: how can i use the const& range variable as a string ? In order to use "find" function for example ?

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni It already is a string. In the first example I elected to show `boost::iterator_range` instead, just to show off. Replace it with `std::string` and it will work exactly the same. Also, note, both examples _already_ "us the const& range variable as a string". The sample prints the strings :)